# What may be the expected percentage of connections that will fallback to TURN?

Tags: webrtc, turn

Say I have built the WebRTC video chat website, some connections after the handshake (ICE Candidates) will go directly p2p, some will use the STUN server, and some will use the "last resort" the TURN server to establish the connection. TURN server based connection is very expensive compared to the direct connection and the STUN connection (which are free) because all traffic must actually go through the TURN server.

How can we estimate the percentage of connections of random users that will need to to go via TURN? Imagine we know very little about the expected audience, except that the majority is in the US. I believe it must be difficult to figure, but my current estimation is somewhere beween 1% and 99%, which is just too wide, can this at least be narrowed down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/what-kind-of-turn-server-is-being-used-d67dbfc2ff5d has some numbers from appear.in which show around 20%. That is global statistics, the stats for the US might be different.

Comment: Checked with US only and this looks a fair bit lower, only around 10% total. Good news for you I suppose :-)